# Check Each Date In Date Range

Tags: sql-server-2008, date-range

In SQL Server 2008 I have a startdate and an enddate being passed to my procedure.  I need to check each date in the range to see if it exists in my validworkday table.  I have no clue where to begin on this, but this is how start/end day are set-up

```
Declare @startdate date, @enddate date
Set @startdate = '01/01/2015'
Set @enddate = '04/16/2015'
```

Now how can I iterate each date in this span to see if validworkday = true for it?  The check I would need to run is like so (checking each date)

```
Select isvalidworkday 
from validworkdays
where date = '01/01/2015'
Select isvalidworkday 
from validworkdays
where date = '01/02/2015'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is syntax that I found from @Incidently years ago (I don't remember where that original post is, but hopefully this will be enough to give the credit), that I still use today.  All I did was slightly tweak his syntax to insert the data into a temp table and add a cursor to iterate each individual date.

```
DECLARE @DateFrom smalldatetime, @DateTo smalldatetime, @firstdate date;
SET @DateFrom='20000101';
SET @DateTo='20081231';
-------------------------------
WITH T(date)
AS
( 
   SELECT @DateFrom 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT DateAdd(day,1,T.date) 
   FROM T 
   WHERE T.date < @DateTo
)
SELECT date 
INTO #AllDates
FROM T OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);

Declare c1 Cursor For

Select date
FROM #AllDates

Open c1 

Fetch Next From c1 Into @firstdate

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
      --Do whatever processing you need here
      Fetch Next From c1 Into @firstdate

End

Close c1
Deallocate c1
```

Answer (score 0):

Code should only live in one place and not be rewritten.  Create functions (once) like GetAllIntsBetween(), GetAllMonths(), GetAllDates(), etc.  Then used them like:

```
DECLARE @startdate date = '01/01/2015', @enddate date = '04/16/2015'

SELECT allDates.TheDate, 
isnull(v.isvalidworkday, false) AS isvalidworkday 
FROM dbo.GetAllDates(@startdate, @enddate) AS allDates
LEFT JOIN validworkdays AS v
ON allDates.TheDate = v.MyDate
```

The GetAllDates() would be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetAllDates(@Start DATETIME, @End DATETIME)
RETURNS
@AllDates TABLE
(
TheDate DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN

    IF @Start > @End
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Temp DATETIME
        SET @Temp = @Start
        SET @Start = @End
        SET @End = @Temp
    END

    WHILE @Start <= @End
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @AllDates
        VALUES(@Start)

        SET @Start = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Start)

    END

RETURN

END
```

(note: can change DATETIME to DATE)